# com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Unable to find a javac compiler;
[image: Environment variable setting]

com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.

Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.

It is currently set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111`

I'm getting this error when i try to run CMD file.
[image: Eclipse setting]

Comment: That's a Java Runtime Environment. For people merely running Java applications, not developing them. It's possible that it doesn't come with the java compiler classes.

Comment: You need to install a JDK, not just a JRE.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111;

Comment: already i have installed JDK

Comment: please look at my latest img

Comment: Do you have environment variables set up to that path? That would be main concern here in JDK and JVM

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK

In ECLIPSE, Set the installed JRE setting to the JDK - in the project (project properties -> Java Build Path-> Libraries), or global default in preferences (Java->Installed JREs). The eclipse setting is stronger than the system variable

[it is points to SE1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps2RF.png)

Try this also:

- Eclipse, access the menu: "Window -> Preferences"
- Go to "Ant -> Runtime", at the tree;
- Go tothe Classpath tab;
- Go to and Expand the "Global Entries" item;
- In Global Entries, the path to `tools.jar` was wrong. It was pointing to an older version of Java;
- removed the wrong entry and added the correct one with "Add External Jars" button.

Comment: project properties -> Java Build Path-> Libraries is point  to SE1.8

Comment: if i run using eclips then no issue.but i am trying to run using ANT in cmd.